# Why these space are in my table?

Tags: html-table, cell, space

Can you help me please how remove these spaces? [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP0ki.gif) shows my problem:

[image]

Can anybody solve my problem?

Comment: Use <td valign='top'>

Comment: Thanks dear Yograj Gupta, My problem solved. But is there any way to remove bottom space in this image: [link](http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag17/nima_pw/Untitled_zpsebebcf43.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use valign attribute for 1st and 3 rd td.

```
<tr><td valign="top"></td><td></td><td valign="top"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks dear pavan Teja, My problem solved. But is there any way to remove bottom space in this image: [link](http://i1296.photobucket.com/albums/ag17/nima_pw/Untitled_zpsebebcf43.gif)